# clang: error no such file or directory: */Debug-iphonesimulator/MailCore/MailCore

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mailcore2

I am using mailcore2 in my ios app from fetching my gmail account emails on my device. I have changed the ios sdkversion from 6.1 to 6.0 in the mailcore2 scripts bcz I am trying to compile and run the app using iPhone simulator 6.0 which uses ios sdkversion 6.0. Doing so I am getting the following clang error.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/shujaat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTestApp-ditognlaoajwldfliplqecnxqbfj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MailCore/MailCore'
```

While trying to compile and run my app using iphone simulator 6.1 (uses ios sdk 6.1), with no changes in the ios sdk version in the shell scripts, I am getting the following error:

```
/bin/sh /Users/shujaat/Documents/WemoTech/Products/WantList/sourcecode/ThirdPartyLib/MailCore2/Externals/builds/workdir/20130930192723/src/libetpan/build-mac/update.sh
configuring

running prepare-cyrus-sasl.sh
```

prepare sources

patching file lib/client.c

building tools

generated makemd5i386 properly

building for iPhoneOS - armv7

CONFIGURE FAILED

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

These issues are driving me crazy for the last couple of days. Need your help.

Comment: Does it work when you run it on your iPhone but not in the simulator?

Comment: @AdamG It's a compiler error, so how can it?

Comment: It's a compile error for the simulator, not the iPhone.  When you compile frameworks you have to compile them for two different architectures ARM and i386, the issue could be in the simulator compiler.

Comment: @AdamG Thanks for the response. I haven't tried it on iPhone, I am going for it now.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks, if it's a compiler error than how it can be fixed. Can u  guide me please.

Comment: Where are those shell script from and what do they contain?

Comment: @AdamG But that's not running it, that's compiling it.

Comment: @trojanfoe this is the link of those scripts https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/tree/master/scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These issues are fixed now. I want to explain what I did to get rid of them for others facing same issues:
I made a separate project, and made mailcore2 as a part of it (didn't include the #import  line in any of the project files at first). I compiled and run the project and copied the resultant mailcore 2 from it to my original project. It's compiling and running fine now.

Comment: #import <MailCore/MailCore.h>

Answer (score 0):

Go to  your main project target->"Build phases"->"Target dependencies" add **mailcore2 ios**

<strike>You need to read [Check Adding MailCore to Your iOS Project](https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore) carefully.</strike>

Comment: I am using mailcore2, https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore2. I have added it to my project the way it's said.

Comment: hmm, man your problem is in the static library `static mailcore2 ios`, check it if added properly.

Comment: it's added and during compilation a folder with the name "Externals" along with 8 subfolders i.e. "builds","ctemplate-ios","icu4c-ios","installed","libetpan-ios","libsasl-ios","prebuild","tidy-html5-ios" are creating.

Comment: I checked, the said directory or file is existing at /Users/shujaat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTestApp-ditognlaoajwldfliplqecnxqbfj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/MailCore/MailCore. I have copied and pasted it in the Debug-iphonesimulator folder and the path for it is /Users/shujaat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyTestApp-ditognlaoajwldfliplqecnxqbfj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MailCore/MailCore now . That error is gone but now I am facing another error i.e ld:can't map file, errno=22 for architecture i386. What should I do now.

Comment: @ShujaatHussainBangash this is not the right way (copy/paste), you need to do it right, try add the MailCore2 from zero, there is a good video can help.